# Swift 3 - Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

Tags: swift, xcode

I got this error and I don't know how to solve it !
I'm searching all solutions but can't solve it!

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider
>   breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

**Edit :**

```
    func createTarget(id: Int) {

        listdata = dbHelpr.getDatabase(rowId: id)

        for data in listdata {

            let lengthOfChar : CGFloat = data.ans.length
            let yAxis : CGFloat = self.view.frame.height / 2 + 70

            var width: CGFloat = view.frame.size.width - 40 // frame width
            var targetWidth: CGFloat = (width - (lengthOfChar - 1) * 5) / lengthOfChar
            var totalWidth: CGFloat = (targetWidth * lengthOfChar) + ((lengthOfChar - 1) * 5)

            if targetWidth > 50 {
                targetWidth = 50
            }

            for tar in data.ans.characters {


                var xAxis : CGFloat = (width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2) + (tar * targetWidth) + (tar * 5) + 20

                let targetLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xAxis, y: yAxis, width: targetWidth, height: 5.0))
                targetLabel.backgroundColor = .white
                targetLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
                targetLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
                targetLabel.text = String(describing: tar)
                targetLabel.textAlignment = .center
                targetLabel.textColor = .white
                self.view.addSubview(targetLabel)

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: `let preAxis1: GCFloat  = (width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2); let preAxis2: GCFloat  = (tar * targetWidth) + (tar * 5) + 20; let xAxis : CGFloat = preAxis1 + preAxis2 ` ? Or break it again... and find which part seems to pose issue.

Comment: Excuse me I'm so sorry the (tar) is character and give 2nd error (Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Character' and 'CGFloat') @Larme

Comment: Why should `tar` be a Character? That doesn't make sense.

Comment: See a question after editing @Larme

Comment: `for (indexTar, tar) in data.ans.characters.enumerated(){` and in `let xAxis =` replace the `tar` with `indexTar`.

Comment: Thank you dear, it's working now!
Thank you very much :) 
@Larme

Comment: Excuse me bro the last question, now my characters showing from left, how to convert from left to right ? because my characters are Arabic. @Larme

Comment: I guess that you have to rethink your logic on how you create `xAxis`.

Comment: I created xAxis to show my characters in the center of the screen because I'm creating Puzzle Word project @Larme

Comment: Good explain ? @Larme

Comment: That should be another question.

Comment: No just how to convert characters from left to right for example my word is (London) but show me inversion (nodnoL) This example is in English  @Larme

Comment: No. You had an issue, I fixed it. Now your issue is to change the behaviour, so that should be another question.

Comment: Did you mean I should write a new question on the site ?? @Larme

Comment: YES, that's what I meant. A new question with your fixed code.

Comment: Well, wait! @Larme

Comment: This link a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45242109/swift-3-convert-characters-from-right-to-left-or-left-to-right) @Larme

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Expression was too complex to be solved in reasonable time; consider
>   breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions

So as said, break it:

```
let preAxis1: GCFloat = (width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2) 
let preAxis2: GCFloat = (tar * targetWidth) + (tar * 5) + 20
let xAxis : CGFloat = preAxis1 + preAxis2
```

Now, that reveals another (the real one) issue, and what you are doing doesn't make sense:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Character'
>   and 'CGFloat'

So `tar` is a `Character`, not a "numeral".
There is no sense about using it in the calculation of `xAxis`. What you want in fact is the index of it.

Instead of `for tar in data.ans.characters {`, you can do it like that:

```
for (indexTar, tar) in data.ans.characters.enumerated() {
```

You are iterating all the `characters` in `data.ans` and `indexTar` is the current index and `tar` the `Character`.
So by replacing `tar` with `indexTar` in the previous calculation of `xAxis` it makes more sense and should work.

Comment: I prefer `for i in 0..<data.ans.characters.count` to loop through an array when I only need the index.

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs when sub-elements of the expression are not having the type that they should. Check whether `width`, `totalWidth`, `tar` and `targetWidth` are `CGFloat`s as well.

If they are not, cast them to `CGFloat`:

```
let xAxis : CGFloat = (CGFloat(width) / 2) - (CGFloat(totalWidth) / 2) + (CGFloat(tar) * CGFloat(targetWidth)) + (CGFloat(tar) * 5) + 20
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the basic arithmetic operators you are using have a lot of overloads and hence type inference takes too long for the compiler to do, so you should either convert each of your values to CGFloat or break up the expression into several lines.

Breaking up the expression into several lines:

```
var xAxis : CGFloat = (width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2)
xAxis += (tar*targetWidth)
xAxis += (tar*5) + 20
```

Converting to CGFloat:

`let xAxis : CGFloat = (CGFloat(width) / CGFloat(2)) - (CGFloat(totalWidth) / CGFloat(2)) + (CGFloat(tar) * CGFloat(targetWidth)) + (CGFloat(tar) * 5) + CGFloat(20)`

Comment: Excuse me I'm so sorry the (tar) is character and give 2nd error (Cannot invoke initializer for type 'CGFloat' with an argument list of type '(Character)') @DávidPásztor

Comment: How do you expect to multiply a `Character` by a number? Of course that won't work. Please explain what you are trying to achieve and why do you think you need to multiply  `Character` by a number.

Comment: OK you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45209791/set-frame-cgrect-per-devices-by-count-of-characters-swift-3) @DávidPásztor

Comment: That doesn't explain what `tar` should at all. Please include in your question the part of code where you define and use tar and try to explain more clearly than in your other question what do you expect to get from multiplying a `Character` by a number.

Comment: OK, my project is a puzzle word and my cell called from SQLite database but my cell is string and I did converted my cell to character I'm using tar in loop to increment label by tar when is character, is this explain enough ?? @DávidPásztor

Comment: That still doesn't explain at all why would you want to use a `Character` to calculate the x position of something. You might want to use the `label.text.characters.count`, which is an `Int` and from what I understood from your vague explanation might be what you need.

Comment: I want from character to be located in the center of X axis and smaller and biggest by count of characters. Now I'm editing my question and add my all code, OK ?? @DávidPásztor

Comment: Do you found a solution to my question ? @DávidPásztor

Comment: It is still not clear what exactly you are trying to achieve, but I think you should be using `data.ans.characters.count` instead of `tar` in the problematic line.

Comment: Hi, could you see [my new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266999/swift-3-uibutton-adding-settitle-from-plist-and-database) and help me ? @DávidPásztor