# Swift 3- Convert characters side from right to left or left to right

Tags: swift, for-loop, char, character

I created xAxis to show my characters in the center of the screen because I'm creating Puzzle Word project, **now my issue is my characters showing from left, how to convert from left to right ??** because my characters are Arabic.

For example my word is (London) but show me inversion (nodnoL) This example is in English. **So how to fix this issue convert to right side or left side ??**

This my code :

```
for (indexTar, tar) in data.ans.characters.enumerated() {

    let x : CGFloat = (width / 2) - (totalWidth / 2)
    let xx : CGFloat = (CGFloat(indexTar) * targetWidth) + (CGFloat(indexTar) * 5) + 20
    var xAxis : CGFloat = (x + xx)                    
    let targetLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: xAxis, y: yAxis, width: targetWidth, height: 5.0))

    .....
}
```

Comment: `var xAxis : CGFloat = (x + xx); xAxis = width - xAxis`?

Comment: Thank you dear :) @Larme

Comment: Hi, could you see [my new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266999/swift-3-uibutton-adding-settitle-from-plist-and-database) and help me ? @Larme

Comment: There's a whole document for dealing with Right to Left (RTL) languages https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages/SupportingRight-To-LeftLanguages.html in iOS