# Swift 3 - CGAffineTransform does not work

Tags: swift, uiview, uibutton, cgaffinetransform

I'm creating a button programmatically and `CGAffineTransform` does not work in my project when adding in `addTarget`, why?

**EDIT :**

```
func createButtonPuzzle(id: Int) {

     for i in 1...14 {

            let btnButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
            btnButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2, width: 100, height: 100)
            btnButton.backgroundColor = .blue
            btnButton.setTitle("iButton", for: .normal)
            btnButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

            view.addSubview(btnButton)   
     }
}


func moveButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if sender.tag == 1 {

        if sender.transform == CGAffineTransform.identity {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: 
            sender.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 100)

            })
        }                
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the view positioned using autolayout or autoresizing? This won't probably work with autolayout.

Comment: Not using autolayout or autoresizing, it was already working but now it does not work ! @Sulthan

Comment: Have you set  breakpoint? Do you know if it's actually reaching the transform? Why are you requiring a parameter name for `moveButton`?

Comment: I don't set breakpoint, and I'm creating moveButton function because btnButton created in another function @dfd

Comment: None of your created buttons have `.tag = 1` so you will never execute code inside `if sender.tag == 1` statement

Comment: Excuse me, Could you help me please in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266999/swift-3-uibutton-adding-settitle-from-plist-and-database) ?? @Sulthan

Comment: Excuse me, Could you help me please in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266999/swift-3-uibutton-adding-settitle-from-plist-and-database) ?? @dfd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function, instead of using sender.transform, use btnButton.transform, this is caused because you are out of scope, and sender might be dismissed, which causes the animation to dismiss.

Another option is to strongly hold the object:

```
let tappedButton : UIButton = sender
```

and then use tappedButton

**EDIT**

I mean something like this:

```
func moveButton(sender: UIButton) {

    if ((sender.tag == 1) && (sender == self.btnButton)) {

        if self.btnButton.transform == CGAffineTransform.identity {

            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: 
                self.btnButton.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 50, y: 100)

            })
        }                
    }
}
```

**EDIT - 2**

According to your code there are 2 problems:

1. All 14 buttons are stacked 1 on top of the other, meaning button 14 will be the topmost button instead of button 1.
2. You are not setting the tag, and then it fails in your check in moveButton:

   func createButtonPuzzle(id: Int) {

   ```
    for i in 1...14 {

           let btnButton = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
           btnButton.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width / 2, y: self.view.frame.size.height / 2, width: 100, height: 100)
           btnButton.backgroundColor = .blue
           btnButton.setTitle("iButton", for: .normal)
           btnButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(moveButton(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

           **btnButton.tag = i // This is missing **

           view.addSubview(btnButton)   
    }
   ```

   }

And then this fails:
 **if sender.tag == 1 {**

So to test it and see it working, first you need to either go from 14 to 1 and just from 1..<2 or reposition the buttons in different positions so that it will actually work.

Then the tags will be set and when button with tag 1 will be tapped it will work

Comment: I'm creating btnButton in another function and I'm adding this function in btnButton @unkgd

Comment: Did you check that you actually get to the animation? as @dfd suggested? If you do get there, and everything seems ok, then add your button as a data member to the controller, and use that reference because this means it's being ignored due to it having a weak reference.

Comment: Yes I checked that and I added data to the controller, everything seems OK @unkgd

Comment: I mean, create a button as a data member: fileprivate var btnButton : UIButton, and in the method itself instead of using sender, just check if (self.btnButton == sender), and from that moment on, use self.btnButton instead of sender - edited my answer with what I meant

Comment: A btnButton created in function not in class, just wait editing my code and adding all code @unkgd

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150639/discussion-between-ameen-mk-and-unkgd).

Comment: Excuse me, Could you help me please in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45266999/swift-3-uibutton-adding-settitle-from-plist-and-database) ?? @unkgd